# call to undefined function mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql, wp-cli, xampp

Trying to run a search and replace but am getting an error

```
 Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1688
```

I have checked my WP files and have both mysqli_connect and msql_connect referenced in there. I have tried to replace all mysql_connect references to mysqli_connect however I then get the same error for the new name

```
 Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1688
```

When I run wp --info I get:

```
OS:     Windows NT 10.0 build 18363 (Windows 10) AMD64
Shell:  C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
PHP binary:     C:\PHP7\php.exe
PHP version:    7.4.9
php.ini used:   C:\PHP7\php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:       E:\xampp\htdocs\test
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 2.4.0
```

Comment: Are you installing WordPress for the first time? Does your server meet the [hosting requirements](https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/handbook/server-environment/)? Also, _never_ edit WordPress core files. `mysql_connect` is referenced for backwards compatibility reasons. Your system would use the right mysql function if you had the correct modules installed.

Comment: This is on my local machine, I just installed xampp and haven't used it before. The site I'm moving to xampp is a local localbyflywheel site,  I have moved the SQL database to MySQL server and make a folder in the htdocs 'test' and copied and pasted the wp files from local by flywheel to the xampp/test folder

Comment: Though the site seems to work? I can navigate to it on my local but it straight away redirects me to the old site which is why I am trying to use wp cli to search and replace

Comment: You need MySQL/MariaDB running and you need the MySQLi PHP extension installed. `C:\PHP7\php.exe` is not where XAMPP keeps its PHP though, it looks like your have conflicting PHP installs. This isn't a WordPress problem, this is a local server setup problem

Comment: Where should i go from here then? Ive watched a few tutorials and they have never installed mySQLi extension?